# How can I make the initial value of a TextFormField equal to a variable loaded from shared preferences? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I want to make the initial value of the TextFormField equal to the counter variable. The counter is maintained between app restarts, but when I restart the app, the initial value of the text field is always 0.

Is there a better way of doing that?

(I'm new to programming, sorry if it's a dumb question)

Here's the code I used.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Shared preferences demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Shared preferences demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCounter();
  }

  //Loading counter value on start
  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  //Incrementing counter after click
  _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
      prefs.setInt('counter', _counter);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              initialValue: '$_counter',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the result of your initial attempt (output, return value, error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a controller for `TextFormField` and update the value after getting it from `SharedPreferences`. 
Something like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Shared preferences demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Shared preferences demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  int _counter = 0;
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCounter();
  }

  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
      myController.text = _counter.toString();
    });
    
  }

  _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
      prefs.setInt('counter', _counter);
      myController.text = _counter.toString();
    });
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.